# Dynamic dtsConfig file selection

Tags: c#, configuration, ssis

Our .NET application currently calls an SSIS package.

Is there a way, without introducing new variables to the package itself, that we can use .NET to instruct SSIS which .dtsConfig file to use for a connection manager?

Comment: Have you had a chance to evaluate my answer? Does it solve your needs? If it does not, could you please provide feedback on your question? If it has resolved your issue, please mark the appropriate answer by selecting the outline of a green checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are invoking the package via [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx), look at setting the ConfigFile option. If this is via a .net library, the [ImportConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.importconfigurationfile.aspx) method will be your friend.